# My daughter got married last year in late August, can I still claim her part year?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

If my 21-yr-old daughter lived at home (and I provided more than half of her support) until her wedding in late August of last year, can't I still claim her as a dependent of some sort?

Comment: What country are you in, as it certainly makes a difference in tax law?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume your question pertains to the United States.  (Odds are good, I think.)

What I've determined is:  I can't answer yes/no based on the limited information above, and my findings.

But, do refer to the criteria below which I found at [IRS.gov - A "Qualifying Child"](http://www.irs.gov/newsroom/article/0,,id=133298,00.html) to determine if your daughter still qualifies for your tax return last year.  Here are some of the salient points, with **my emphasis added** where I think you need to pay particular attention:

> In general, to be a taxpayer’s
>   qualifying child, a person must
>   satisfy four tests:
>
> - Relationship — the taxpayer's child or stepchild (whether by blood
>     or adoption), foster child, sibling or
>     stepsibling, or a descendant of one of
>     these.
> - Residence — **has the same principal residence as the taxpayer
>     for more than half the tax year.**
>     Exceptions apply, in certain cases,
>     for children of divorced or separated
>     parents, kidnapped children, temporary
>     absences, and for children who were
>     born or died during the year.
> - Age — must be under the age of 19 at the end of the tax year, **or
>     under the age of 24 if a full-time
>     student for at least five months of
>     the year, or be permanently and
>     totally disabled at any time during
>     the year.**
> - Support — did not provide more than one-half of his/her own support
>     for the year.
>     ...
>
> **Additional Rules**
>
> While the four qualifying child tests generally apply
>   for the five tax benefits noted above,
>   there are some additions or variations
>   for particular provisions:
>
> Dependent — a qualifying child must also meet these tests:
>
> - Nationality — be a U.S. citizen or
>     national, or a resident of the U.S.,
>     Canada or Mexico. There is an
>     exception for certain adopted
>     children.
> - Marital status — **if
>     married, did not file a joint return
>     for that year, unless the return is
>     filed only as a claim for refund and
>     no tax liability would exist for
>     either spouse if they had filed
>     separate returns.**
>     ...

So, I think you're OK on the half-year criteria, since you mentioned your daughter got married in August.  But, you'll need to determine if she meets the age requirement (e.g. if still a full-time student, then yes), as well as what kind of tax return your daughter would/will have filed for last year.

[This part of IRS publication 501](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p501/ar02.html#en_US_publink1000220886) goes into more (excruciating) detail and is likely more definitive/current than above, though [IRS.gov](http://www.irs.gov) is the source of each.  Your situation ought to be straight-forward, but if you have difficulty interpreting Publication 501 as it applies to you, please consider consulting a tax professional.  Special life-events often make filing income taxes more complicated than usual.